# Hexadecimal to 8-bit unsigned array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, hex

I have a hexadecimal value,

> 07A5953EE7592CE8871EE287F9C0A5FBC2BB43695589D95E76A4A9D37019C8

Which I want to convert to a byte array.

Is there a built-in function in .NET 3.5 that will get the job done or will I need to write a function to loop through each pair in the string and convert it to its 8-bit integer equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function that will do this.  You will unfortunately have to code one up :(

```
Public Function ToHexList(ByVal str As String) As List(Of Byte) 
  Dim list As New List(Of Byte)
  For i = 0 to str.Length-1 Step 2
    list.Add(Byte.Parse(str.SubString(i,2), Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))
  Next
  Return list
End Function
```

**EDIT**

Qualified the NumberStyles enumeration with the Globalization namespace qualifier.  Another option is to import that namespace and remove the qualifier.

Comment: Thank you for posting that code.  Might be a noob question, but I get NumberStyles is not declared?  I know it would be Dim NumberStyles as ?  Thank you

Comment: @shaiss Try importing System.Globalization in that file.

Comment: Now I get 'Hex' is not a member of 'System.Globalization.NumberStyles'

Comment: NumberStyles.HexNumber seems to work instead of NumberStyles.Hex

Comment: @shaiss, my bad, you're correct.  HexNumber is the value I should have put up there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll find what you are looking for [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/hexencoding.aspx) (codeproject.com)

Comment: I looked at this one as well, I was hoping for something built in to .net